# Force rename files in python

Tags: python, file

I would like to rename files, even if the new name exists, it doesn't matter, it can overwrite it .

```
my_location = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
for filename in os.listdir(my_location + "/static/data/bandsdaily/"):
    if filename.endswith(".json"):
        source = filename       
        destination = filename + ".old"

        print source, destination
        os.rename(source, destination)
```

I am always having this error :

```
20022014.json 20022014.json.old
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/bandsdaily.py", line 89, in <module>
    os.rename(source, destination)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir()` returns *just* the filenames, not full paths. You are trying to rename files in the current working directory instead of `my_location +`/static/data/bandsdaily/`. Prepend the path:

```
path = os.path.join(my_location, "static/data/bandsdaily")
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".json"):
        source = filename       
        destination = filename + ".old"

        print source, destination
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, source), os.path.join(path, destination))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ( ps:  `os.rename( os.path.join(path, source), os.path.join(path, destination))` )